# MEF Import attribute

Tags: c#, import, mef

Using MEF, I know you can do this to import your interface:

```
class MyClass
{
    [Import(typeof(IUser))]

    private IUser m_userName;
}
```

Can I do something similar but within the method? For example, this below does not compile:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
          [Import(typeof(IUser))]
          IUser userName;

          userName.dosomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
IUser userName = container.GetExportedValue<IUser>();

if (userName != null)
{
    userName.dosoething();
}
```

Where 'container' is the CompositionContainer instance:

```
container = new CompositionContainer(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you can't use Imports in that way. In fact you can't ever use an attribute inside method code, so there would be no way to use the attribute in a method.

You can however find exports of a given type by using the container, something like this:

```
IUser userName = (IUser)container.GetExports(typeof(IUser), null, null).FirstOrDefault();
```